# How can I use EJS 'continue' loop keyword in my handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, handlebars.js, ejs

How can I edit my register helper for using continue keyword?

I have a ejs code like this :

```
<% for(let i = iterator; i <= endingLink; i++) { %>
        <% if(i === page) { %>
        <a class="selectedLink" href="/?page=<%=i%>"><%=i%></a>
        **<% continue; %>**  //this keyword confuses me in handblebars
    <% } %>
```

My handlebars.js like this :

```
    {{#for iterator endingLink 1}}


       {{#ifCond iterator '===' page}}

        <a class="selectedLink" href="/?page={{iterator}}">{{iterator}}</a>

        {{/ifCond}}


    {{/for}}
```

register helper:

```
hbs.registerHelper('for', function(from, to, incr, block) {
    var accum = '';
    for(var i = from; i <= to; i += incr)
        accum += block.fn(i);
    return accum;
});
```

Comment: The continue keyword confuses me in  your EJS since **it doesn't do anything**

Comment: Thanks. If it's not working , I can remove it from my code